# Joining/merging multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, append

I have 4 dataframe objects with 1 row and X columns that I would want to join, here's a screenshot of them:

[image]

I would want them to become one big row.

Thanks for anybody who helps!

Comment: Please add the code to generate the two data frames, and how you would like them to be joined, i.e. the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use concatenate in dataframe as below,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'))
df1.loc[0] = [1,1.23,'Hello']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('DEF'))
df2.loc[0] = [2,2.23,'Hello1']

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('GHI'))
df3.loc[0] = [3,3.23,'Hello3']

df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('JKL'))
df4.loc[0] = [4,4.23,'Hello4']

pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis=1)
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Getting a parse error: ParserError: Unknown string format: Close

Comment: It worked now, I just had to .reset_index(drop=True) on each df, thanks!